# How to fetch specific GraphQL object in the nuxt app?

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, vue-apollo

in my Nuxt.js project I've created some dynamic routes and now when I call a page I want to fetch only the associated object from the array by the slug. My query file looks like this:

```
query Project($title: String!) {
  projects(where: {title: $title}) {
    id
    title
    intro
    coverImage {
      url
    }
    functionalFeatures {
      feature
    }
    secondText
  }
}
```

The _slug.vue has following properties:

```
async asyncData({ params }) {
  const slug = params.slug
  return { slug }
},
apollo: {
  projects: {
    prefetch: false,
    query: projectQuery,
    variables () {
      return {
        title: this.slug.replace( '-', ' ').toUpperCase()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error message `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

If I replace `this.slug.replace( '-', ' ').toUpperCase()` with `'Project Title'` everything works fine. Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: you can always check a param ... `console.log(this.slug)` ?

Comment: this proves `this.slug` is undefined in variables fn